# Checking convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fractions

My task is to check whether the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{(-2)^n+n^2}{n2^n}}$$
converges or not. So I tried expanding the fraction like that(should equal to original form):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\frac{2^n}{n2^n}+\frac{n^2}{n2^n}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{2^n}}$$

Then I thought about that the first addend does converge because of Leibniz's rule and the second addend converges because $2^n$ grows much faster than $n$.

But I'm not sure(and rather thinking this form of argumentation is wrong) if I can take addends of a series and prove convergence for each addend instead of proving convergence for the whole series.

I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: You are using as an upper limit the "dummy index" $n$.

Comment: It is a theorem that if $\sum_0^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_0^\infty  b_n$ converge, then $\sum_0^\infty (a_n+b_n)$ converges.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you, corrected it, it should be infinty

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And @AndréNicolas has answered the question.  Are you good to go now?

Comment: Yep, good to go now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st one is $-\ln 2$ (Taylor series).

The 2nd one is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot x^n$$
$$\int \frac{f(x)}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$\therefore f(x)=x\cdot\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)'=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^n=\frac{\frac12}{(1-\frac12)^2}=2$$
So the total sum is $2-\ln2$.

Answer (score 2):

To control if the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{2^n}}$$ you can use the Leibniz's rule. First you have to demonstrate that $$-\frac {1}{n}+\frac {n}{2^n}<0$$ for every $n$. Indeed you can note that rewriting the expression $$-\frac {2^n+n^2}{n\cdot 2^n}<0$$. Therefore now you know that for $n\to \infty$ $$ \frac {1}{n}+\frac {n}{2^n}\to 0$$ therefore you have to demonstrate $$\frac {1}{n}+\frac {n}{2^n}$$ is decreasing proving that the derivate of $f(x)=\frac {1}{x}+\frac {x}{2^x}<0$ after a value of $x$.